# mysql prioritise by field value

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay I have a table with fields

```
Table: comments
    id (primary key, increment, int)
    post_id(foreign key, int)
    user_id (foreign key, int)
    content (text)
    timestamp

Data
1, 1, 1, hello, timestamp
2, 3, 4, 123, timestamp
3, 1, 5, 1245, timestamp
4, 1, 8, test, timestamp
5, 1, 10, hi, timestamp
6, 3, 1, this is 3, timestamp
```

How do I select 5 results out with user_id 1 included in results even though i order by timestamp?

Lets think of the dataset, the the lowest row(5) has the latest timestamp, while 1 has the oldest timestamp.

I need id 1(with user id 1) to be included in the limit 5 even though its timestamp is oldest.

Expected returned rows id:

```
1, 5, 4
```

Not

```
5, 4, 3
```

SQL I came up with not working:

```
SELECT id FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1 ORDER BY user_id = 1, timestamp DESC DESC LIMIT 3
```

How do i do that

Answer (score 1):

You can just order by `user_id = 1`:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM comments
ORDER BY user_id = 1 DESC, timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

This works the following way:
The order by clause: `user_id = 1` will be evaluated to `true` (or more visible to `1`) for the first ID  and `false` (or `0`) for the other rows as they have other user_ids. So you have an imanginary field with `0` and `1` which are ordered `DESC`, return in

```
+----+------+-------------+------------------------+
| id | user | user_id = 1 |       timestamp        |
+----+------+-------------+------------------------+
|  1 |    1 |           1 | oldest timestamp       |
|  5 |   10 |           0 | newest timestamp       |
|  4 |    8 |           0 | some timestamp between |
+----+------+-------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I've edited your question to explain how the boolean order works as the opener seems a beginner. (As of now the edit has to be reviewed)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, ive edited the question a bit, added a foreign key post_id. In this case, if there is a same user_id but different post, will this still works?

Comment: It will work just the same. Just don't forget `DESC` so you can get the `user_id = 1` rows first instead of last.

Comment: Hi, ive tried it with sqlfiddle, its not working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9667e/2

Comment: it returns all rows with user id 1

Comment: You told it `WHERE post_id IN ('64', '63', '60'...` all those have user_id = 1.

Comment: which means i can only use this for `where post_id = 64` , then i have  do to a lot queries N+1 problem. is there a way around it? because a user may leave a comment on multiple posts.

Comment: Well... do you need the comments for a specific user or a specific post?

Comment: actually im loading a set of posts, each posts will have its comments, but user id 1 comments must be on top of others. 1 user can only leave 1 comment on the post.

Comment: about user id 1's comment must be ontop of others only if user id 1 have left a comment on that specific post.

Comment: In that case it is working just fine. The 1-st 5 comments have user_id = 1, and you have `LIMIT 3` so you only see 3 of those.

Comment: hm, its confusing for me. Lets rephrase it,lets say every 5 comments has a same post_id, example, comments 1-5 have post id of 1, while comments 6-10 has post id of 2, comments id 1-5 one of them has user_id=1, i want to select 3 latest comments from each posts(post id 1 and 2) with user_id=1 comment must be on top regardless of its timestamp

Comment: You can either run a separate query for each post or you can get all the comments for the posts with one query, and then filter out the top 3 for each one in the application.

Comment: what if theres 100k comments for a post.

Comment: There is no way to get top 3 of each group in a single query. The problem is not the order.